# Obtener el índice de los elementos de un array

Tags: javascript

Escribir una función en JavaScript que reciba como parámetro un array compuesto
por números enteros y retorne un nuevo array con las siguientes características:

● El nuevo array debe estar compuesto por los elementos que ocupan las
posiciones pares en el array recibido, elevados al cuadrado.

● BONUS: Los elementos del nuevo array deben estar ordenados, de menor a
mayor.

Ejemplo 1:

Dado el array:

```
[7, 3, 2]
```

La función (sin bonus) debe retornar:

```
[49, 4]
```

Nota 1: No se podrán usar las siguientes funciones predefinidas en JavaScript:

- sort
- map
- filter
- reverse

  ```
  function arrayPares(array) {
  let nuevoArray = []

  for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
     if (array[index]%2 != 0) {
         delete array[index]
     } else {
      nuevoArray.push(array[index])
     }
  }
  console.log(nuevoArray)
  }
  ```

Comment: Pon lo que has intentado para poderte ayudar

Comment: intente con un for loop, para ir accediendo a las posiciones pero cuando hago un modulo para igualar a 0 y asi pushear a un nuevo array me di cuenta que me accede a los valores y no al indice, despues de eso me bloquie y no se me ocurre una solucion posible, estoy empezando en esto de Javascript, estoy muy inmaduro aun, sepa disculpar

Comment: Esta pregunta me parece prueba de entrevista técnica… ¿deberíamos fomentar esto? soy partidario de que no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
   if(i % 2 == 0)
   {
      nuevoArray.push(array[i] * array[i]);
   }
}
```

Se recorre el array original y se pregunta si el índice (no el valor del arreglo en el índice) es par, de ser par se añade al nuevo arreglo el cuadrado del elemento del arreglo original.

Para ordenar el nuevo arreglo te recomiendo el **método burbuja**, busca este método en Google, es muy fácil de hacer y hay mucha información, cualquier duda me dices.